# How to skip some content from screen reader

Tags: html, screen-readers, wai-aria

I want to skip some content from reading of screen reader.
consider this html

```
<div id="test" aria-labelledby="test>
   ...
   <div aria-hidden="true">Dont read this content. This content will be loaded from javascript</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Though the aria-hidden=true is set for the div, the content is read by screen reader. Please help to skip this content

Comment: Did you try adding role="presentation" also?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right, how are you testing this?

Not all browsers / screen readers will support this yet.

Try setting style="display:none;" as this may be more widely supported at the moment.

Comment: Its not possible to set the display:none style. Because it should be visible to users. Just want to hide from the screen reader.

Comment: Could you tell us some example content that would be dynamically loaded?

Comment: yes. some additional div will be loaded inside. <div>content1</div><div>content2</div>. The screen reader is reading is as content1, content2. But I dont want it to be readable

Comment: If content contains links set tabindex="-1" on the wrapping div to prevent it from being selected.

But at the end of the day only display: none would work 100%, yes have aria-hidden (or other aria tags) but ultimately the screen reader will decide what is read.